# Meteor: Handlebars able to combine #if and #with?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

Currently, I am pulling info from a third party database, and a template uses that data.

```
<template name="dogTypeData">
  {{#if userOwnsDog typeOfDog}}
    {{#with userOwnsDog typeOfDog}}
      // populate info here with user's dog
    {{/with}}
  {{else}}
    You do not own this kind of dog yet!
  {{/else}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

The helper sees if the owner owns this type of dog:

```
Template.dogTypeData.helpers({
  userOwnsDog: function(typeOfDog){
    return OwnedDogs.findOne({
      type: typeOfDog
    });
  }
});
```

I'm curious if there's a way to combine the `#if` and `#with` statement, or if it is even necessary to do so. For code simplicity and call `userOwnsDog(typeOfDog)` just once instead of twice. Like, is there an `{{#ifwith}}` type of statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them because the the initial `if` is unnecessary here. The same template can be rewritten like this:

```html
<template name="dogTypeData">
  {{#with userOwnsDog typeOfDog}}
    // populate info here with user's dog
  {{else}}
    You do not own this kind of dog yet!
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

Also see [this section](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#with) from [Understanding Spacebars](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize `#with` had a built-in `else`! Looks like its working for me. Thanks, David!

Comment: Yeah spacebars is full of tricks like that. I'm glad you got it working.